# Laravel Routes and Auth

Tags: php, laravel

In my web.php has

```
Route::post('/user/logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
return redirect()->route('login');
})->name('user-logout');

Auth::routes();

Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']
    ], function(){

        Route::get('/','SiteController@index')->name('site.index');

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

            Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');

           

            Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
                Route::get('/', 'AdminControllers\UserController@index')->name('admin.users.index');
                Route::get('/create', 'AdminControllers\UserController@create')->name('admin.users.create');
                Route::post('/store', 'AdminControllers\UserController@store')->name('admin.users.store');
                Route::get('/show/{id}', 'AdminControllers\UserController@show')->name('admin.users.show');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'AdminControllers\UserController@edit')->name('admin.users.edit');
                Route::put('/update/{id}', 'AdminControllers\UserController@update')->name('admin.users.update');
                Route::delete('/destroy/{id}', 'AdminControllers\UserController@destroy')->name('admin.users.destroy');
            });

        });

    });
```

when I try to login with this url

```
http://dev.practice.uz/
```

or with this url

```
http://dev.practice.uz/admin
```

I go to the same login blade and the same route, I should do separately route and login.blade , Can you give Advise me??

Comment: Save yourself work and headaches, just use the same authentication scaffolding for standard users and admin users. If you require the concept of `admin` users, add a column on your `users` table, something like `is_admin`.

Comment: you try `Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {});
Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {});`